# Factory for generic interfaces with Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I have an [`ILoggerFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerfactory) implementation registered in Autofac container. I want to be able to register the following class with Autofac and be able to instantiate it:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(ILogger<Test> logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Works!");
    }
}
```

For that I need to be able to 'teach' Autofac to produce instances implementing the `ILogger<T>` for any class `T`. There are an `ILoggerFactory` extension methods [`CreateLogger<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfactoryextensions#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggerFactoryExtensions_CreateLogger__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggerFactory_) and [`CreateLogger(Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfactoryextensions#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggerFactoryExtensions_CreateLogger_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggerFactory_System_Type_) that are able to produce instances of required type, but I can't wrap my head around how to make Autofac to call them.

If I wanted non-generic `ILogger`, I'd write

```
containerBuilder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger("default"))
```

but I'm not sure what to do for the generic one. Any pointers?

**Update**: After reading some more [documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html), I came up with this:

```
public class LoggingModule: Autofac.Module
{
    private readonly MethodInfo mi;

    public LoggingModule()
    {
        this.mi = typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions)
            .GetMethod(nameof(LoggerFactoryExtensions.CreateLogger), new[] { typeof(ILoggerFactory) });
    }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    private void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
            new[]
            {
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, i) => IsGenericLoggerParameter(p.ParameterType),
                    (p, i) => CreateLogger(this.mi, p.ParameterType, i.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>())
                    )
            });
    }

    private static bool IsGenericLoggerParameter(Type parameterType)
    {
        return parameterType.IsGenericType && parameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILogger<>);
    }

    private static object CreateLogger(MethodInfo mi, Type typeArg, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Type genericArg = typeArg.GetGenericArguments().First();
        MethodInfo generic = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { genericArg });
        return generic.Invoke(null, new[] { loggerFactory });
    }
}
```

And then:

```
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Test>().AsSelf();
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule<LoggingModule>();
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        var test = container.Resolve<Test>();
```

works. Issue is I don't fully understand how it works (and, more importantly, how it might break), so I'm still looking for more elegant and/or understandable solutions.

Comment: Wich part of the code are you not understanding ?

Comment: I don't understand what parameters are and how they work.

Answer (score 6):

I found out a simple answer, but only for the `ILogger<T>` from the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` package: using the `ServiceCollection` from the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package:

```
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging(); // all the magic happens here
        // set up other services 
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Populate(services); // from the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package
        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        Test t = container.Resolve<Test>();
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Autofac and need to inject Microsoft ILogger< T > into objects, you must add the following to the ContainerBuilder

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
//loggerFactory.AddProvider(LogProvider) //If you need another provider than Microsoft logger
builder.RegisterInstance(loggerFactory).As<ILoggerFactory>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>)).SingleInstance();
```

Object who need to inject ILogger< T > will now get the correct ILogger

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering after a year to provide clean solutions for AutoFac v6

### If you want to add Microsoft.Extensions.Logging ...

This cleanest way to add ILogger<T> (From Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) with AutoFac is to register Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory implementation, and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger<T> generic class.

The Logger<T> class is decorator class, inside Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions library, which wraps the actual ILogger implementation, but doesn't actually implement concrete logger (console logger, EventLog logger, etc.). The Logger<T> has constructor with parameter of type ILoggerFactory, which is used to create ILogger concrete implementation.

**Solution**

```cs
static ContainerBuilder CreateBuilder()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterInstance(LoggerFactory.Create(config => config
        .AddConsole()
        .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
    ));

    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>));

    return builder;
}
```

### If you want to register generic service with complicated constructor logic...

As for the literal answer to the question: I would recommend to use **RegisterGeneric** method.

**Example**

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric((context, types) =>
{
    var factory = context.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();
    return factory.CreateLogger(types[0].FullName);
}).As(typeof(ILogger<>));
```

Answer (score 0):

YAY so glad you posted this:
With your example I got it working for ILogger and ILogger

```
  public class LoggingDependencyRegistrationModule : Autofac.Module
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _lf;
    private readonly MethodInfo _mi;
    private readonly Type _t;

    public LoggingDependencyRegistrationModule(ILoggerFactory lf)
    {
        _lf = lf;
        _mi = typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(LoggerFactoryExtensions.CreateLogger), new[] { typeof(ILoggerFactory) });
        _t = typeof(ILogger);
    }
    private void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[]
        {
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, i) =>
                            _t.IsAssignableFrom(p.ParameterType),
               (p,i)=>{

                    if(p.ParameterType == _t)
                       return _lf.CreateLogger(t.ToString());

                    return  CreateLogger(_mi, p.ParameterType, _lf);
                   }
               )
        });
    }
    private static object CreateLogger(MethodInfo mi, Type typeArg, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Type genericArg = typeArg.GetGenericArguments().First();
        MethodInfo generic = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { genericArg });
        return generic.Invoke(null, new[] { loggerFactory });
    }


    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterInstance(_lf).SingleInstance();
        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```